# Connection failure. You must change the jdbc7.jar at org.talende

Tags: talend

Can you tell me  the exact location where jar file need to be copied. A jar will be required for the below issue.

```
Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
  org.talend.utils.exceptions.MissingDriverException: can not find class :oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  missing JDBC driver :
  ojdbc7.jar
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataUtils.connect(ExtractMetaDataUtils.java:1128)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.testConnection(ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.java:315)
      at org.talend.metadata.managment.repository.ManagerConnection.check(ManagerConnection.java:289)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$59.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:3812)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$59.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:1)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$1.runnableWithCancel(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:77)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$ARunnableWithProgressCancel$1.call(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:161)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Somehwere into your classpath?!

Answer (score 0):

In Talend, try to go to Windows>Show View..>Modules. There you can import or download external jar files for your components.